# setting up mongodb replica sets

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am a newbie to mongo db and looking to set up a replica set. I am confused though as how I can achieve this.

I want to have a primary, secondary and arbiter of 3 different machines, each running mongo.

I have been trying to set it up but have made a mess of it I think! How can I remove any replica sets/configuration I have in place?

I have installed mongo, and pointed each instance of mongo at a config file like this:

```
logpath=D:\mongodb\log\mongo.log 
logappend=true
dbpath=D:\mongodb\data
directoryperdb=true
port = 27017
replSet = rsMySet
```

From here though, I am not sure what to do. I have read a number of articles, examples etc but all is confusing.

Could someone provide step by step instructions of how it can be done?

Also, I want to connect to this replica set from a C# web application. What should my connection string point at? the primary, secondary or how does it work? Also, what user should be used to access mongo? I use integrated security when accessing sql server, is the same possible here?

Thanks,
Niall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the basic steps which I followed to create a replica set in my local machine.

```
Step 1 : 

Start all mongods with replSet argument 

mongod --replSet SriReplSet  --dbpath /Volumes/Data/Replica-DBS/1 --port 27001 --logpath /Volumes/Data/Replica-DBS/log/log.1 --logappend --fork
mongod --replSet SriReplSet  --dbpath /Volumes/Data/Replica-DBS/2 --port 27002 --logpath /Volumes/Data/Replica-DBS/log/log.2 --logappend --fork
mongod --replSet SriReplSet  --dbpath /Volumes/Data/Replica-DBS/3 --port 27003 --logpath /Volumes/Data/Replica-DBS/log/log.3 --logappend --fork
```

"SriReplSet" is the name of your replica set. Obviously, dbpath and port will change according to your configuration.

I am planning to make the first one ( with port number 27001 ) as primary. So logged into first mongod and set my configuration as below.
Note that am using localhost as everything is in my local machine.

```
Step 2 : 
>x={
    _id :"SriReplSet",
     members : [
         {_id : 0, host :"localhost:27001"},
         {_id : 1, host :"localhost:27002"},
         {_id : 2, host :"localhost:27003"},
     ]
}

> rs.initiate(x)
{
    "info" : "Config now saved locally.  Should come online in about a minute.",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Above command  will initiate the replica set and will show up a message saying " Config now saved locally.  Should come online in about a minute."
and you are done :)

```
Step 3 : 

SriReplSet:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "SriReplSet",
    "date" : ISODate("2013-05-16T05:35:18Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "localhost:27001",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 370,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1368682493000, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-05-16T05:34:53Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "localhost:27002",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 20,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1368682493000, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-05-16T05:34:53Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-05-16T05:35:18Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "localhost:27003",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 5,
            "stateStr" : "STARTUP2",
            "uptime" : 18,
            "optime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-05-16T05:35:17Z"),
            "pingMs" : 736
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Note that, the first one is primary.

Am not a C# guy, but in Java we can connect to a replica set using the Java driver ( mostly same is the case with C# i guess ) by passing several a list of ServerAddress to the Mongo constructor. The drivers are replica aware, they will change accordingly if primary changes.

By default, all read and write operations will be made on the primary. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps outlined here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#deploy-a-development-or-test-replica-set

The way to remove any mistaken configurations would be to drop the "local" database.

```
> use local
> db.dropDatabase()
```

Lots of examples how to connect to a replica set are here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format